# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'. Estoy teniendo problemas obteniendo el canal de texto

Tags: python, flask, discord.py

He probado muchas cosas y no he encontrado la solución al error, el ID del canal de texto es el adecuado.

(Esta es la fracción de código que da error)

```
async def onPOST():
  try:
    channel = bot.get_channel(994211790667927562)
    await channel.send(request.json)
    return "Good request"
  except:
    print("Except")
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(994211790667927562) 
    await channel.send(request.json)
    return "Good request"
```

Comment: Estas en Stack Overflow en español. Podrias traducir tu pregunta o eliminarla y preguntar en el sitio en ingles por favor? De lo contrario terminara cerrada.

Comment: @DanteS. Ya lo traducí, perdón pensaba que estaba en el sitio en inglés.

Comment: No pasa nada, todos nos equivocamos c: Pero hablando de tu problema, eso de que get_channel devuelva None está dentro del comportamiento esperado de discord.py. Como dice [la documentación](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel), bot.get_channel devuelve None cuando el canal no fue encontrado. Revisaste que la id del canal esté bien escrito? Revisaste que tu bot tenga los [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html) necesarios para poder buscar canales?

Comment: Si no tienes los intents necesarios habilitados, prueba con esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65792091/12913664

Comment: Como antes comente, el ID del canal es correcto, y el bot tiene rangos de administrador, quiero decir que tiene todos los permisos necesarios y más.
También creo pensar que la línea número 1 es correcta, ya que antes hice algunas pruebas y funcionó. @DanteS.

Comment: Una cosa son los permisos que tiene el bot, otra son los intents. Quizá no tienes los intents habilitados. Probaste con lo que dice el OP en la pregunta en inglés que te pasé? No se habilitan del todo desde el developer portal, también tienes que activarlos desde tu código (por default discord.py habilita varios por vos, pero puede no ser suficiente). Aquí hay otra pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work

Comment: He estado leyendo sobre los intents y no veo que se necesite activar ningún intent para obtener canales a partir de un ID, pero por si acaso lo he probado, y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Mmmmm, dices que tiene los permisos, tanto en el developer portal como en los intents (supongo que habilitaste los privilegied intents). El bot está en el mismo grupo que el canal? Si no es nada de eso, entonces no se por que pueda ser...

Comment: Exacto, tiene todos los permisos en el Discord, ya que tiene el rol de administrador, también le di todos los intents utilizando Intents().all(). Y si el bot está en el canal de texto.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución al problema, el problema consistía en que no estaba utilizando la función.

```py
await bot.login(token, boolean)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.login

Que es necesaria antes de poder utilizar

```py
await bot.fetch_channel(id)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_channel

Answer (score 0):

*bot.get_channel* puede returnar None en caso de que el canal no esté en la caché del bot. De todas formas, puedes fetchearlo para conseguir el objeto del canal.

```
await bot.fetch_channel(994211790667927562)
```

Esto hace una request a discord, por lo que no debes usarlo demasiado seguido.

Otra opción sería usar un TextChannelConverter, que intenta buscarlo primero en la caché, y si no está, hace una request.

```
await commands.TextChannelConverter.convert(ctx, "994211790667927562")
```

Ten en cuenta que estos dos métodos crearán un error si no pueden convertirlo.

Comment: He utilizado _await bot.fetch_channel(994211790667927562)_ para obtener el canal, y no ha funcionado. Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'. El error se encuentra en la línea 30 que es justo la de await bot.fetch_channel. Ahora actualizo el codigo.